# how to use google login link to my login page using django-allauth?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-urls, django-allauth

I have created a project which is working nicely.
I have a login page, signup page and profile page (as myspace). I just want to add an additional funtionality to my login page which is a user can login using google, fb, or instagram. but when i added the django-allauth to my project. it overwrite the existing login page.
I just want to add an icon of google login. and not the whole page how i can do so.

[my login page looks like this earlier and at bottom i added a google icon in which i want to add the functionality of auth app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeZWC.png)

[login pages is looking like this for now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oGa8.png)

**Update:-**

what i thought is how django-allauth works, that i just need to add a url in login page with `<a href >` tag with 'allauth/google' or something like this.

what i see is i need to add a new path in `urls.py` for allauth which automatically create a login, signup and profile page.

**problem which i figure out is**

I have an accounts_app app in my project. the url for `accounts_app` is same as `allauth` thats why it overwrite the template

url.py of camorid_project

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('camroid_app.urls')),
    path('accounts_app/', include('accounts_app.urls')), -----i want to add allauth functionality to this url
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),    -------------i don't want to add this because it create an inbuilt templates

    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

what i want is i don't want to change login, signup and myspace page and i want to add icon in my login page with google login on click of which a user would be able login to the website.

Comment: What templates and view functions were you using before and after? Could you share the code for those?

Comment: i figure out the problem but don't know how to solve it. i 'm updating my question for you.

Comment: @bouteillebleu i have updated my ques i hope this would help

Answer (score 0):

in your login.html add `{% load socialaccount %}`
and then  `<a href="{% provider_login_url 'google' %}"</a>`
this link will make you login with google api.
and you can style the button if you wnat..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).